# Android Custom EditText set custom default style if none provided

Tags: android

I have created a custom view (to be provided as a library) that I want it to use a default style if none is provided by the user when using it in their project.

```
class SuggestionTextView
@JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = androidx.appcompat.R.attr.editTextStyle
) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

this style is in my module and I want to use it if the dev doesn't provide one of his own:

```
 <style name="Widget.AppCompat.SuggestionTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="imageTintColor">@color/myBlue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/myBlue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/myLightGray</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_white_border_gray</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/SuggestionTextViewTextAppearance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SuggestionTextViewTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

if the user provides their own when using my view I want to use that one instead, i.e:

```
<com.mypackage.suggestionscomponent.SuggestionTextView
            android:id="@+id/suggestionTextView"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.UserCustomSuggestionTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textHeader" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this (Google really making it hard).

1. Create your declare-stylable for your custom view (custom properties only) on attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="SuggestionTextView">
    <attr name="nResults" format="integer" />
    <attr name="language" format="string" />
    <attr name="imageTintColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

2. Create an attr for your THEME on attrs.xml as well

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTheme">
    <attr name="customSuggestionTextViewStyle" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

3. Create your default style on styles.xml *(custom attr in step 1 don't have android:xx, i.e: imageTintColor)*:

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.SuggestionTextView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="imageTintColor">@color/myRed</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/myBlue</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_white_border_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/myLightGray</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/SuggestionTextViewTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="SuggestionTextViewTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
   <item name="android:textSize">33sp</item>
   <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

4. Create your theme on themes.xml and set your attr customSuggestionTextViewStyle to the style created on step 3.:

```
<style name="SuggestionTextViewTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="customSuggestionTextViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.SuggestionTextView</item>
</style>
```

5. Setup your custom view constructor using ContextThemeWrapper with our theme on 4. on the super call, defStyleAttr to be our custom attr on step 2, load custom attributes on init, remember to call recycle().

```
class SuggestionTextView
@JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.customSuggestionTextViewStyle
) : AppCompatEditText(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.SuggestionTextViewTheme), attrs, defStyleAttr) {

init {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.SuggestionTextView,
            defStyleAttr, R.style.SuggestionTextViewTheme
        ).apply {
            try {
                nResults = getInteger(R.styleable.SuggestionTextView_nResults, 3)
                language = getString(R.styleable.SuggestionTextView_language) ?: "en"
                imageTintColor = getColor(
                    R.styleable.SuggestionTextView_imageTintColor,
                    ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.myRed)
                )
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
}
```

6. Use custom control in your activity, using custom style created on step 3.:

```
<com.mypackage.suggestionscomponent.SuggestionTextView
    android:id="@+id/suggestionTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

7. Create another style to override the default (if needed)
8. Apply new style:

```
<com.mypackage.suggestionscomponent.SuggestionTextView
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DifferentSuggestionTextView"
     android:id="@+id/suggestionTextView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

That's it :)